# retrieve selection from ul list built with php variables

Tags: jquery

I have a UL list in one div, built using php that retrieves data from mysql. Here is the code:

```
<div class="sidebar_section">
<h1>Browse Categories</h1>
<?php
include('config.php');
//Connect to mysql server
...
//Select database
...
$categories_sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_catagory";
$categories_query = mysql_query($categories_sql) or die (mysql_error());
$rsCategories = mysql_fetch_assoc($categories_query);
?>
<form>
<ul>
<?php do { 
?>
<li><a href = "#" id="cat_<?php echo $rsCategories['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $rsCategories['CatagoryName']; ?></a></li>
<?php
} while ($rsCategories = mysql_fetch_assoc($categories_query));
?>
</ul>
</form>
</div>
```

How do I get the user's selection into another .php file so that I can display only the products associated with this category? Of course, in the other file I'd do SELECT * FROM table WHERE categoryname=whatever the user selected.

Comment: session variable? http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this varies a lot.

First I will try to answer with the easiest approach I can think of:

Make the href of the anchor something like this:

```
<li><a href="category.php?catId=<?php echo $rsCategories['ID']; ?>" 
       id="cat_<?php echo $rsCategories['ID']; ?>">
    <?php echo $rsCategories['CatagoryName']; ?></a></li>
```

Then just create a category.php script in which you use the id from the $_GET array.

```
<?php
$categoryId = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['catId']);
$products_sql = "SELECT * FROM ebook WHERE category = '$categoryId'";
//proceed with the rest
?>
```

Since you're going with links in a list and you are using # as href, I will consider that you might desire on using AJAX. Here is one way of doing all this.

First: let's give those lists a class, which we will call "category-choose" (awful naming, sorry, just change it as you wish). This will allow that a single jQuery .click or .live('click', ...) will be enough, instead of having to add one event per id.

```
<li><a href="#<?php echo $rsCategories['ID']; ?>" 
       class="category-choose">
    <?php echo $rsCategories['CatagoryName']; ?></a></li>
```

Second: just to make it easy on us, let's use the href as "#" (where  is just a number indicating the id). Now we can do the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.category-choose').live('click', function () {
        var catId = this.href.substr(1);
        $("#content_right").load('content_displaycatproducts.php?catId=' + catId);
    });
});
```

Now, in the PHP script you do the same done in the previous method.

Hopefully I didn't screw up somewhere since I have no way to test this code :) Any errors or malfunctioning you get, please report and I will fix ASAP.

Comment: To be honest, I'm just learning, so I don't know if I need ajax or not. I was toying around with $(document).ready(function() {
$('a#cat_<?php echo ($rsCategories['ID']); ?>').click(function() {
 $('#content_right').load('content_displaycatproducts.php');
 });
});

Comment: By the way, I really appreciate the quick reply! Thank-you!

Comment: jQuery .load method is an ajax GET request under the hood. I will update my answer to fit your needs.

Comment: I put this in but it's still displaying all the db rows. In the files content_displaycatetories.php I've got a mysql query: SELECT * FROM ebook WHERE category = .... I need to pass the selection to this statement. That's why I wrapped the UL in a form. Could I use the catID variable in the function? Can you actually use variables in a mysql statement?

Comment: <?php
//db connection
...
//setup query
$sql="SELECT * FROM ebook";
//store result in variable
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo '<div class="product_box">';
echo '<h1>' . $row['booktitle'] . '</h1><img src="images/image_01.jpg" />';
echo '<div class="product_info">';
echo '<p>' . $row['description'] . '</p>';
echo '<h3>' . '$' . $row['price'] . '</h3>';
echo '<div class="yellowButton">';
echo '<a href="">Buy Now</a>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
}

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to add a proper code block in the comment.

Comment: It is a good idea if you can provide it by editing your post. That way it can have better format and other people looking at the answer will be able to see it easier. You can't add a code block in the comment. On the topic: Check the PHP code in my answer, the second code block. That should work, just change it to ebook and to whatever the column name is.

Comment: By the way, should it be $(document.ready).ready(function()... or $(document).ready(function()...

Comment: That was a typo I fixed a couple of updates before. Check the post the way it is right now (just one ready :P)

Comment: No more errors now, but nothing displays. I suspect it's my sql statement: $sql = "SELECT * FROM ebook WHERE categoryname IN (SELECT categoryname FROM tbl_catagory WHERE ID = '$categoryId')";  I tried the one you posted above but I don't have a catID in the ebook table, only in categories. I have to select where the categoryname in each table matches.

Comment: Usually, when you work with MySQL or other relational databases, you don't keep the name for the relation, but the id. This facilitates joins and makes things faster. On your query, you wrote "tbl_catagory" instead of "tbl_category".I just realized you used catagory also in your original question.  I recommend doing an echo of the $sql variable to see what query is being generated and then running that on MySQL

Comment: The typo was intentional due to someone else's typo when creating the database :) I just realized my mistake. You are absolutely right. I need another field in ebook (catID) that will be the foreign key referencing the catID in the categories table. How does one remember all this???? Thank-you ever so much for all your help! You'd make a great teacher.

Comment: I teach >_> If you think the answer is good enough, it would be appreciated if you accepted the answer. That way others can see the question was answered if they ever search for something similar.